# Div content in same line

Tags: html, css

Following is the js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/zk7Uf/1/

```
<div style="width:200px">
    <span class="span-blankPDF">
        <label for="Employments_2b6131a8-d5c3-40d6-85f7-ecec0d315e56__ReasonForLeaving">Reason for Leaving:</label>
    </span>
    <div class="div-PDF" style="display: inline;width: 50px;">Reason  to  livelong</div>
</div>
```

The result i want is like this with the above divs width should not be increased.

```
Reason for leaving:Reason  
                   to  livelong
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for here

Comment: Could you try to clarify exactly what you're trying to do?  Are you looking to keep all of the content within the width of the outermost div?

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zk7Uf/2/?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for :

http://jsfiddle.net/BY294/

```
<div style="width:200px">
<span class="span-blankPDF" style="float:left">
    <label for="Employments_2b6131a8-d5c3-40d6-85f7-ecec0d315e56__ReasonForLeaving">Reason for Leaving :</label></span>
    <div class="div-PDF" style="display: block;width: 50px; float:left">Reason to livelong</div>
    </div>
```

Position them baby!

You want the span to float left so it has a point of reference, then you want the next div to be a block as its its own entity as such and float that left to 'lean' on the span you have..

Or else i have completely misunderstood the question, in which case im not to blame! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `span` element should remain a `span` and the `div` inside should remain a `div`, you can do it nicely with some CSS.

Use the `display: inline-block` to get rid of how `span` and `div` position themselves by default. Then use `vertical-align: top` to make the elements in the same line align on top of their containers.

So, without changing the widths (as you requested) and just adding some CSS, you can write it like this:

```
<div style="width:200px;">
    <span class="span-blankPDF" style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
        <label for="Employments_2b6131a8-d5c3-40d6-85f7-ecec0d315e56__ReasonForLeaving">Reason for Leaving</label>
    </span>
    <div class="div-PDF" style="display:inline-block;width:50px;vertical-align:top;">Reason  to  livelong</div>
</div>
```

Se live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Vg6RG/

**EDIT:** You get the same result sa *Pogrindis* suggested, but this one is not using floating.